# sqlite3 ошибка в коде near "(": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram

Ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProject\pythonProject10\lesson1\app\database.py", line 18, in cmd_start_db
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO (tg_id) accounts VALUES ({key})".format(key=user_id))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Основной код:

```
async def cmd_start_db(user_id):
    user = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE tg_id == {key}".format(key=user_id)).fetchone()
    if not user:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO (tg_id) accounts VALUES ({key})".format(key=user_id))
        db.commit()
```

Comment: Собери запрос в отдельной переменной, с подстановкой, и покажи, что получилось.

Comment: "Операции SQL обычно должны использовать значения из переменных Python. Тем не менее, остерегайтесь использования строковых операций Python для сборки запросов, поскольку они уязвимы для атак путем внедрения SQL инъекции." https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/sqlite3.html#:~:text=SQL%20operations%20usually%20need%20to%20use%20values%20from%20Python%20variables

Comment: Можете приложить хоть названия таблиц?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает на строке 18 в функции cmd_start_db. В этой строке происходит попытка выполнить SQL-запрос для вставки значения user_id в таблицу accounts. Для исправления этой проблемы, вам необходимо указать правильное имя таблицы после ключевого слова INSERT INTO. Например, если имя таблицы - accounts, то SQL-запрос должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```sql
cur.execute("INSERT INTO accounts (tg_id) VALUES ({key})".format(key=user_id))
```

Также код содержит возможные SQL-инъекций. Для исправления этой проблемы есть несколько возможных решений, одна из них это использование параметризованных запросов. Вместо прямой вставки значения в строку запроса, используйте параметризованные запросы с заполнителями. Это помогает предотвратить атаки SQL-инъекций и обеспечивает правильную обработку значений. Вот пример, как изменить код с использованием параметризованных запросов:

```py
async def cmd_start_db(user_id):
    user = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE tg_id = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
    if not user:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO accounts (tg_id) VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
        db.commit()
```